# Can I use a list of sockets to send to multiple clients?

Tags: java, list, sockets, server

I have a `ArrayList<Socket> listOfSockets` that adds a socket when I receive `clientsocket = serversocket.accept()` like this `listOfSockets.add(clientsocket)`
and then I send this whole list to another class like this.

```
Server_Client client = new Server_Client(clientSock, clientSocketList);
                    Thread X = new Thread(client);
                    X.start();
```

Here is the code for my class that I send the list and socket to

```
public class Server_Client implements Runnable{
//ArrayList<String> UserNameList;
ArrayList<Socket> clientSocketList;
Socket socket = null;

public Server_Client(Socket X, ArrayList<Socket> L){
    this.socket = X;
    this.clientSocketList = L;
}


@Override
public void run() {
    try {

        ListenforMessage NewMessages = new ListenforMessage(socket);
        Thread myThread = new Thread(NewMessages);
        myThread.start();            
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.err.println(e);
    }
}
//------------------------------------------------------------------
//Class that handles incoming messages!
class ListenforMessage implements Runnable{
    Socket socket;
    DataInputStream IN;
    DataOutputStream OUT;
    public ListenforMessage(Socket x) {
        this.socket = x;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        try {
            while (true) {                    
                    IN = new DataInputStream(socket.getInputStream());
                    OUT = new DataOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
                    String message = IN.readUTF();
                    //System.out.println(message);
                    for (Socket TEMP_SOCK : clientSocketList) {
                        if(TEMP_SOCK != this.socket){ 
                            SendMessage(message);
                        }
                    }
                }                                                  
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(Client.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    }                        

}

public void SendMessage(String m) throws IOException{
    try {            
        DataOutputStream OUT = new DataOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
        OUT.writeUTF(m);
        System.out.println("User said: " + m);
    } catch (Exception e) {
    }

}
//------------------------------------------------------------------
}
```

In the `ListenforMessage` class, in the for-loop I go trough the size of list and if `TEMP_SOCK` is not `this.socket` then I want to send a message to that socket, and if it is then don't do anything. But my problem is that when I connect with 2 clients they can't send message to each other. They just send the message to the server and the server sends back the message to the client. My question is, can you use a list like I do to check if the socket is not the socket that you are YOURSELF.

cause now Client1 sends a messages and receive the same messages from sever, and Client2 does the same thing.
I want Client1 to send and Client2 to receive the message(And other sockets on the same list)

Comment: Question #1: why on earth are you creating a thread that starts a (temporary) thread and then terminates? That will make your child thread unmanageable.

Comment: `ListenforMessage` should implement `Runnable`, not extend `Thread`

Comment: Oh yeah my bad. I have that in my code now. I just added that to see if it made any change (It didn't)

Comment: Your code is a huge mess of a design. You should look up an example, of which there should be plenty (you are after all describing basically a chat server). If you try to continue with this, it won't end well.

Comment: This is for a school project meaning that I will not implement this in anyway untill I get more experience with this sort of code or atleast not onto any product. I just need help to figure out the problem not your condescending :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code doesn't work because you should let `SendMessage` know to which socket it should send the message (i.e. you should pass `TEMP_SOCK` to it), instead, you're making it use the `socket` variable, which is the socket connected to the client that just sent the message.

Comment: Thank you! It was so simple :)